# How to save a model-instance using serializers in django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I would like to save a class instance in my database using serializers, provided by DRF.
**Serializer**:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'
```

here I try to save an instance:

```
p = Person(Name = "Test")
_srlz = PersonSerializer(data = p)
```

The real case is little bit more complicated, but sanse the same.
Unfortunately the data - _srlz.data is empty. So if I try to save data via _srlz.save() method then nothing change.
Otherwise if I request an existed object

```
p = Person.objects.filter(id = 1)
_srlz = PersonSerializer(data = p)
```

Then my _srlz.data will **not** be empty.

How should I save this object if datasource is not JSON-object, but model-class instance?Should I first serialize it and then deserialize again?

I already tried to save instance calling a .save() method, provided by model's default Manager, but I would like to separate my model and service methods so all database operations performed by serializers.
Or is it OK in this case, because I deal not with pure JSON, but with model instance? But how can I then validate data?

Comment: just `p.save()`. No need to wrap it through a serializer/deserializer.

Comment: I just newbie on django. So I have to use serializers only if data comes from outside?
And why my serializer is empty?

Comment: a serializes converts a Django model instance to JSON/XML/Yaml/... and vice-versa. That is its main purpose.

Comment: seems that this is works. I have another problem tho, but this exact question is closed